# elasticsearch generate query using resthighlevel client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl, resthighlevelclient

I have to generate below query using rest high level client and i have tried the following query but it is not able to form the query as below wanted to know where it is going wrong in my current aggregation code top hits should appear before the sum aggregations and also i am using rest high level client to connect to the elastic search.

Required Query:

```
{
    "aggregations": {
        "by_destination": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "destinationLocation.keyword",
                "size": 10,
                "min_doc_count": 1,
                "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                "order": [
                    {
                        "_count": "desc"
                    },
                    {
                        "_key": "asc"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "aggregations": {
                "by_trans": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "transportMode.keyword",
                        "size": 10,
                        "min_doc_count": 1,
                        "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                        "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                        "order": [
                            {
                                "_count": "desc"
                            },
                            {
                                "_key": "asc"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "aggregations": {
                        "by_sourcelocation": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "sourceLocation.keyword",
                                "size": 10,
                                "min_doc_count": 1,
                                "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                                "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                                "order": [
                                    {
                                        "_count": "desc"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "_key": "asc"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "aggregations": {
                                "by_shipdate": {
                                    "terms": {
                                        "field": "shipDate",
                                        "size": 10,
                                        "min_doc_count": 1,
                                        "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                                        "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                                        "order": [
                                            {
                                                "_count": "desc"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "_key": "asc"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "aggregations": {
                                        "by_arrival": {
                                            "terms": {
                                                "field": "arrivalDate",
                                                "size": 10,
                                                "min_doc_count": 1,
                                                "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                                                "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                                                "order": [
                                                    {
                                                        "_count": "desc"
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "_key": "asc"
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            "aggregations": {
                                                "docs": {
                                                    "top_hits": {
                                                        "size": 10,
                                                        "_source": [
                                                            "id"
                                                        ]
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "quantity": {
                                                    "sum": {
                                                        "field": "transferQuantity"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "transfercost": {
                                                    "sum": {
                                                        "field": "transferCost"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "revenueRecovered": {
                                                    "sum": {
                                                        "field": "revenueRecovered"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Code:

```java
TopHitsAggregationBuilder topHitsAggregationBuilder = AggregationBuilders.topHits("top").fetchSource("id", "").size(1);

    AggregationBuilder itemAgg = AggregationBuilders.terms("by_item").field("item.keyword");

    AggregationBuilder destinationAgg = AggregationBuilders.terms("by_destination").field("destinationLocation.keyword");

    AggregationBuilder transportAgg = AggregationBuilders.terms("by_trans").field("transportMode.keyword");

    AggregationBuilder sourceAgg = AggregationBuilders.terms("by_sourcelocation").field("sourceLocation.keyword");

    AggregationBuilder shipDateAgg = AggregationBuilders.terms("by_shipdate").field("shipDate");

    AggregationBuilder arrivalDateAgg = AggregationBuilders.terms("by_arrival").field("arrivalDate");

    AggregationBuilder quantityAgg = AggregationBuilders.sum("quantity").field("transferQuantity");
    AggregationBuilder transferCostAgg = AggregationBuilders.sum("transfercost").field("transferCost");
    AggregationBuilder revenueRecoveredAgg = AggregationBuilders.sum("revenueRecovered").field("revenueRecovered");


    AggregationBuilder aggregation = itemAgg.subAggregation(destinationAgg
            .subAggregation(transportAgg.subAggregation(sourceAgg.subAggregation(shipDateAgg.subAggregation(arrivalDateAgg)
                    .subAggregation(topHitsAggregationBuilder).subAggregation(quantityAgg)
                    .subAggregation(transferCostAgg).subAggregation(revenueRecoveredAgg)))));

    //searchSourceBuilder.size(0);
    searchSourceBuilder.aggregation(aggregation);
    searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
```

actual generating is:

```
 {
    "aggregations": {
        "by_item": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "item.keyword",
                "size": 10,
                "min_doc_count": 1,
                "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                "order": [
                    {
                        "_count": "desc"
                    },
                    {
                        "_key": "asc"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "aggregations": {
                "by_destination": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "destinationLocation.keyword",
                        "size": 10,
                        "min_doc_count": 1,
                        "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                        "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                        "order": [
                            {
                                "_count": "desc"
                            },
                            {
                                "_key": "asc"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "aggregations": {
                        "by_trans": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "transportMode.keyword",
                                "size": 10,
                                "min_doc_count": 1,
                                "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                                "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                                "order": [
                                    {
                                        "_count": "desc"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "_key": "asc"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "aggregations": {
                                "by_sourcelocation": {
                                    "terms": {
                                        "field": "sourceLocation.keyword",
                                        "size": 10,
                                        "min_doc_count": 1,
                                        "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                                        "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                                        "order": [
                                            {
                                                "_count": "desc"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "_key": "asc"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "aggregations": {
                                        "by_shipdate": {
                                            "terms": {
                                                "field": "shipDate",
                                                "size": 10,
                                                "min_doc_count": 1,
                                                "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                                                "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                                                "order": [
                                                    {
                                                        "_count": "desc"
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "_key": "asc"
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            "aggregations": {
                                                "by_arrival": {
                                                    "terms": {
                                                        "field": "arrivalDate",
                                                        "size": 10,
                                                        "min_doc_count": 1,
                                                        "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                                                        "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                                                        "order": [
                                                            {
                                                                "_count": "desc"
                                                            },
                                                            {
                                                                "_key": "asc"
                                                            }
                                                        ]
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "top": {
                                                    "top_hits": {
                                                        "from": 0,
                                                        "size": 1,
                                                        "version": false,
                                                        "explain": false,
                                                        "_source": {
                                                            "includes": [
                                                                "id"
                                                            ],
                                                            "excludes": [
                                                                ""
                                                            ]
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "quantity": {
                                                    "sum": {
                                                        "field": "transferQuantity"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "transfercost": {
                                                    "sum": {
                                                        "field": "transferCost"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "revenueRecovered": {
                                                    "sum": {
                                                        "field": "revenueRecovered"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Top_hits will not accept a sub aggregation. If  don;t have  knowledge of Java but I think you need to change .subAggregation(topHitsAggregationBuilder.subAggregation(quantityAgg) to .subAggregation(topHitsAggregationBuilder).subAggregation(quantityAgg) . Top_hits return documents if you intend to  sum of quantiy for each "id" use terms aggregation instead of top_hits

Comment: but i need document values in the aggregation response

Comment: Does changing  subAggregation(topHitsAggregationBuilder.subAggregation(quantityAgg) to .subAggregation(topHitsAggregationBuilder).subAggregation(quantityAgg)  works?

Comment: nope i have updated the effect of this in the question section just it is missing aggregation keyword i am almost there

Comment: missing aggregation keyword ? Ididn't get what is the issue now?

Comment: if you see the question section i have updated the query which is generated after your suggestion but it is not inside "aggregation"only it has "top"

Comment: I tried it , it ran succcessfully. top_hits returns documnets so its format is hits:{}

Comment: Yeah it ran for we as well! i was blindly thinking compared to your query it was missing aggregation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top_hits aggregation doesn't accept sub aggregations. So solution was to change 
below query

```
.subAggregation(topHitsAggregationBuilder.subAggregation(quantityAgg)
```

to

```
.subAggregation(topHitsAggregationBuilder).subAggregation(quantityAgg)
```